# Changes in generating function expansion corresponding to changes of GF

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, combinatorial-species

Is there systematic review of how various transformations of GF affect its expansion? For EGF part of this is theory of species, but how about OGFs?

Comment: See [formal power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Notes on Generating Functions](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~genovese/class/iprob-S06/notes/generating-functions.pdf). Listed operations: right-shifting, left-shifting, derivatives, shift-derivative combinations, partial summation, integration, scaling, extraction of sub-sequences, composition.